# discord.py on_member_ban with no perms

Tags: python, discord.py, python-3.9

Is it possible to know whenever a member gets banned using on_member_ban (or any other possible method) in a server without having any ban/admin permissions?

Comment: The bot doesn't need `ban_members` permissions to execute `on_member_ban`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you don't need ban permissions to view them.

However, you do need to enable [ban intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Intents.bans), but that is enabled by default so in most cases you don't need to worry about it.

A simple event like this executes even when the bot does not have permission:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_ban(guild, member):
    print(f'Member was banned in {guild.name}: {member.id} ({member})')
```